# Two tables, Three prices, Different periods, What can i do?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting

I have tried and failed to solve this puzzle, and now im looking for some nice help if anyone is out there. Explanation:

**First table consists of the original price on a item.**

```
Table1 (Sales_Data): 
+---------+----------+-------+------------+
| Item_Id | Store_Id | Price | Sales_Date |
+---------+----------+-------+------------+
```

**Second table consists of two prices**

- one is if a store has another price on the item and this has a 0 value in To_Date
  because this price should last forever.(Lets call this forever price)
- one is if a store has another price on a item for just a period (02.03.2014-10.03.2014) lets call this discount
- both prices is stored in Price, but the dates are the big difference.

  ```
  Table2 (Discount_Data): 
  +---------+----------+-------+------------+
  | Item_Id | Store_Id | Price | Sales_Date |
  +---------+----------+-------+------------+
  ```

**Now to the big Q:**

1. Forever price should always overwrite original price
2. Discount price should always overwrite original/or forever price for the exact period
3. Item_Id, and Store_Id has to be the same.
4. How can i go forward to solve this? Can anyone help me on the way?

Comment: Can you show us your query? Also the result it is giving you and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to make an assumption, but it appears your second table should include two more columns, From_Date and To_Date. I will alias Discount_Data forever price as ddf and Discount_Data period price as ddp

```
select sd.Item_Id, 
    sd.Store_Id, 
    sd.Price as OriginalPrice, 
    coalesce(ddd.Price,ddf.Price,sd.Price) as UpdatedPrice
from Sales_Data sd
left join Discount_Data ddf
  on sd.Item_Id=ddf.Item_Id
    and sd.Store_Id=ddf.Store_Id
    and sd.Sales_Date >= ddf.From_Date
    and ddf.To_Date=0
left join Discount_Data ddp
  on sd.Item_Id=ddp.Item_Id
    and sd.Store_Id=ddp.Store_Id
    and sd.Sales_Date between ddp.From_Date and ddp.To_Date
```

Hope that helps.